# Minimize $\{tr^Trt^T\}_{ii}$ subject to $r^Tt=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, pseudoinverse

I want to solve the following optimization problem over $r,t\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$:

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \{tr^Trt^T\}_{ii}\\\quad r,t\\ \text{subject to} & r^Tt=1\end{array}

My attempt: since $r^Tr$ is scalar and $\{tt^T\}_{ii}=t^2_{i}$ , we can rewrite above problem as:

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & r^Trt^2_{i}\\\quad r,t\\ \text{subject to} & r^Tt=1\end{array}

Can I replace $r^T$ by its pseudo-inverse $r^T=(t^Tt)^{-1}t^T$? Then

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac{t^2_{i}}{t^2_{1}+t^2_{2}+\cdots+t^2_{n}}=0?\\\quad t\end{array}

What I want is to minimize each diagonal element of $\{tr^Trt^T\}_{ii}$ as much as possible., subject to $r^Tt=1$, we can assume that diagonal elements of $t$ are ordered in nondecreasing order.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers. Give 'em a try.

Answer (score 0):

For any give $T$, we can rewrite the optimization problem as follows:
\begin{array}{cl}
\operatorname{minimize}_{R}& RR'\\
\operatorname{s.t.} & RT=1
\end{array}
The Lagrangian is
$$L=RR'+\lambda(RT-1)$$
The optimality conditions are
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial R}&=2R+\lambda T'=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}&=RT-1=0
\end{aligned}
So, $R=-\frac{\lambda}{2}T'\Rightarrow-\frac{\lambda}{2}T'T-1=0\Rightarrow\lambda=\frac{-2}{T'T}$

Therefore, the optimal $R$ is $R = (T'T)^{-1}T'$.

You are right!!!

If you want to minimize all elements, you should construct some proper problem, for example
\begin{array}{cl}
\operatorname{minimize}_{T,R}& \sum_{i}\{TRR'T'\}_{ii}\\
\operatorname{s.t.} & RT=1
\end{array}

Comment: Where did $i$ go?

Answer (score 0):

In vector terms, minimize $r^2t^2$ subject to $r\cdot t=1$; by Cauchy-Schwarz, this happens with value $1$ when $r=t$ is a unit vector.

Comment: What is the square of a vector?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo With [summation over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), $r^2=r_jr_j$. Note that $(tr^Trt^T)_{ii}=(tr^T)_{ij}(rt^T)_{ij}=t_ir_jr_jt_i=r_jr_jt_it_i$.